# Scroll down and Update Listview C#

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a ListView in my UWP app.

This is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="viewMedias" SelectionMode="None" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        ......
</ListView>
```

Now, how can I receive an event when this ListView scrolls to nearly end? I want to Update ItemsSource to add new Items to bottom of the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!
What you want to achieve is called Incremental Loading. You don't have to implement it by your self - just check existing solutions.
**Windows Community Toolkit** has `IncrementalLoadingCollection` helpers that can help you. You can check demo in their sample app: [Windows Community Toolkit Sample App in Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (go to *helpers > Incremental Loading Collection*). Here is some sample code from this app:

```
// Defines a data source whose data can be loaded incrementally.
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleSource : IIncrementalSource<Person>
{
    private readonly List<Person> _people;

    public PeopleSource()
    {
        // Creates an example collection.
        _people = new List<Person>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            var p = new Person { Name = "Person " + i };
            _people.Add(p);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        // Gets items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters.
        var result = (from p in _people
                      select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        // Simulates a longer request...
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        return result;
    }
}

// IncrementalLoadingCollection can be bound to a GridView or a ListView. In this case it is a ListView called PeopleListView.

var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>();

PeopleListView.ItemsSource = collection;

// Binds the collection to the page DataContext in order to use its IsLoading and HasMoreItems properties.
DataContext = collection;

// XAML UI Element
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Is Loading: {0}'}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HasMoreItems, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Has More Items: {0}'}" />
```

Comment: thank you. I get items of the server. and each request get me 20 items. so how i can **when** scroll go to end, send an other request and add new items to the _people

Comment: IIncrementalSource has method called GetPagedItemsAsync. This is the place where you should request for more items. You have to create your own Source adapted for your case.

Comment: Also please note, PeopleSource instance is the ItemsSource here. _people variable is just a helper variable used to simulate real source of data (like server).

Comment: Yes I know, But I don't want to get all the requests first.
I need to have an event that when ended scroll, I will send a request to the server at that time. and add to _people 
Your code is only for the UX
I need an event to send a request to the server and get new 20 items other

Comment: GetPagedItemsAsync is your 'event' here. If you set ItemsSource to your custom source (eg. PeopleSource), GetPagedItemsAsync will be called when ListView is scrolled to bottom. What is returned from GetPagedItemsAsync is automatically added to bottom of your ListView.